# In VIM, what do the letters and codes mean on the other, unfocused tabs (e.g. \S\r\b\m\filename.txt)

Tags: vim

What do those codes mean in the unselected tab (e.g. \S\r\b\m\filename.txt) and it is possible to hide them, make the tab titles a uniform size and ellipsized? For instance, the tabs in a browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, this is how vim abbreviates filesystem paths. `/home/me/devel/secretproject/src/foo.c` gets abbreviated to `/h/m/d/s/s/foo.c`, giving you slightly more clue as to where the file is than an ellipsis would (assuming you somewhat know the structure of the underlying filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the `tabline` (or `guitabline` in gVim). See `help setting-tabline` for detailed information, including an illustrative example. If you are familiar with customising the statusline, then this is achieved in a similar way.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a nice way of making each tab the same width, so it will probably require a printf() command in the MyTabLine() function.

It could be a nice challenge!